# What happens paperwork wise when you are granted asylum in Canada? Is there a certificate?

Tags: canada, refugees

Someone claims they were granted asylum in Canada and showed a document briefly. While it is easy to find Canadian citizenship certificates samples online (and I happen to have one too) I can't find any such document for asylum. How does this work?

Comment: There must be some sort of residence permit, but I can't find a source mentioning one.

Comment: I was hoping maybe someone who was granted asylum would chime in with their experience.

Comment: I know a few (long since naturalized) resettled refugees, but I do not know any asylum claimants as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://irb.gc.ca/en/applying-refugee-protection/Pages/index5.aspx, when a decision is made on a refugee protection claim, the Refugee Protection Division (RPD) will send a written Notice of Decision, along with an explanation of the reasons for this decision. The RPD also sends a copy to Immigration, Refugees, and Citizenship Canada (IRCC), and to the Canada Border Services Agency (CBSA).

An accepted claim gives the applicant “protected person” status. This means they can stay in Canada, and can apply to become a permanent resident of Canada.

Answer (score 0):

One document that they might receive is called a [Refugee travel document](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Refugee_travel_document). They are similar to passports but are issued in the name of the country where the asylum seeker is claiming refuge. Canada is also supplying these documents and they [look like the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Front_cover_of_a_Canadian_travel_document_issued_to_refugees_under_the_1951_convention.jpg):

[image: Refugee Travel Document]

Note that this document is only needed if the refugee wishes to temporarily leave Canada, so in general asylum seekers might not possess them. If they do however it is an official document.